# Not able to plot the heatmap of one column with respect to others

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, heatmap, correlation

With the help of the question: [Correlation heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39409866/correlation-heatmap), I have tried the following:

```
import pandas
import seaborn as sns 
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("training.csv", header=0,index_col=0)
for a in list(['output']):
    for b in list(dataframe.columns.values):
        corr.loc[a, b] = dataframe.corr().loc[a, b]
        print(b)
print(corr)
sns.heatmap(corr['output'])
```

I got the following error:

```
IndexError: Inconsistent shape between the condition and the input (got (8, 1) and (8,))
```

I do not want to have the all values correlation heatmap with all values. I only want to have the correlation of one column with respect to others.

Kindly, let me know what I am missing.

Comment: Often when you get something like this `(8, 1) and (8,)` you just need to reshape the `(8,)` to also be `(8,1)`. Lets say array `X` is `(n,)`. to get it to be `(n,1)` then either `X.reshape(-1,1)` or `X[:,np.newaxis]`

Comment: But have you just tried to replicate the examples from seaborns docs? https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need to check the example you have suggested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to build a heatmap from `pd.Series` - this does not work. `pd.Series` is a 1D object, while `seaborn.heatmap()` is commonly used for 2D data structures.

`sns.heatmap(corr[['output']])` - will do the job

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3],[5,4,3],[5,4,12]],index=[0,1,2],columns=['A','B','C'])
df.corr().loc['A',:]
```

Out[13]:

A    1.0

B    1.0

C    0.5

Name: A, dtype: float64

```
sns.heatmap(df.corr().loc[['A'],:])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helped me.

Comment: Just for question how I can increase the plot size as I am using jupyter the visual is too small to see. Can you help me?

Comment: matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [30.0, 30.0]. You might also want to set up 'lines.linewidth', 'lines.color', 'font.size', 'figure.dpi' and 'legend.markerscale' parameters

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
sns.heatmap(corr['output'])
```

`corr['output']` is a `pd.Series`. The [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) states

> > > `data` : rectangular dataset
> > >
> > > 2D dataset that can be coerced into an ndarray. If a Pandas DataFrame is provided, the index/column information will be used to label the columns and rows.

You write

> > > I do not want to have the all values correlation heatmap with all values. I only want to have the correlation of one column with respect to others.

In this case, why a heatmap? Your data is one dimensional. You might want to use a barchart, for example, using [`pd.DataFrame.corrwith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html):

```
dataframe.corrwith(dataframe['some_specific_column']).plot(kind='barh')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The case is right now I am just using one column. But in future I may use 2 or 3, which is then I might need heatmap to judge the correlation.