# How to set center color in heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I want to plot a heatmap in seaborn. My code is following:

```
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 13
plt.rcParams['font.weight'] = 'bold'
my_dpi=96
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(800/my_dpi, 600/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi, facecolor='black')
rdgn = sns.diverging_palette(h_neg=130, h_pos=10, s=99, l=55, sep=3)
sns.heatmap(df, cmap=rdgn, center=0.00, annot=True, fmt ='.2%', linewidths=1.3, linecolor='black', cbar=False, ax=ax)
plt.savefig('./image/image.png', dpi=96, facecolor='black')
```

And the result is following:

[image]

I want the set 0 to be white, and the value >0 to be red, the values which <0 to be green. But the center in heatmap is invalid.

By the way, how to set the color unsymmetrical. Because the min value in my data is -0.34 and the maxima is 1.31. I want to set 0 to be white, -0.34 to be greenest and 1.31 to be reddest.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`center` would require something that *can* be centered. So instead of a palette, which is a list of colors, you will need a colormap. Seaborn provides the `as_cmap` parameter for this case,

```
sns.diverging_palette(..., as_cmap=True)
```

Alternatively, you can of course use any other matplotlib colormap, or specify your custom colormap.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = np.linspace(-0.34, 1.31, 100).reshape(10,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rdgn = sns.diverging_palette(h_neg=130, h_pos=10, s=99, l=55, sep=3, as_cmap=True)
sns.heatmap(data, cmap=rdgn, center=0.00, annot=True, fmt ='.0%', 
            linewidths=1.3, linecolor='black', cbar=True, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If instead of centering the colormap you want to shift its middle point you cannot use `center`. But instead a `matplotlib.colors.DivergingNorm`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import DivergingNorm
import seaborn as sns

data = np.linspace(-0.34, 1.31, 100).reshape(10,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rdgn = sns.diverging_palette(h_neg=130, h_pos=10, s=99, l=55, sep=3, as_cmap=True)
divnorm = DivergingNorm(vmin=data.min(), vcenter=0, vmax=data.max())
sns.heatmap(data, cmap=rdgn, norm=divnorm, annot=True, fmt ='.0%', 
            linewidths=1.3, linecolor='black', cbar=True, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Here, the full colormap will be squeezed in the green part and stretched in the red part.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. One more question, can make -34% in the top left corner greener?

Comment: As said, you can use any colormap you like. If none of the [predefined matplotlib colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html) work for you, and if you're not happy with the [seaborn options](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html), you can [define your own colormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html).

Comment: Maybe I have not  Explain my problem clearly. Because the minimum value of my data is -0.34 and the maximum value of my data is 1.31, it is not symmetrical. I want the color bar is also unsymmetrical, which is light green in -0.34 and dark red in 1.31 now. I want it can be also dark green in -0.34.

Comment: Ok, that's not what `center` does. I updated the answer.

Comment: Nice! Thank you.

Comment: `DivergingNorm` renamed to `TwoSlopeNorm` https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.2.0.html?highlight=divergingnorm#divergingnorm-renamed-to-twoslopenorm

Comment: Also, in Seaborn's plotting functions, some require `hue_norm = <TwoSlopNorm object>`, not `norm = ...` now.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `vmin` and `vmax` [parameters](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) of seaborn.heatmap might help you:

```
sns.heatmap(df, cmap=rdgn, annot=True, fmt ='.2%', linewidths=1.3,
            linecolor='black', cbar=False, ax=ax, 
            vmin=-0.34, vmax=1.31)
```

However there doesn't seem to be a way to also set the center to 0 for non-divergent color maps, so if that is a required feature then you can't use seaborn.heatmap. The best you could do would be to set `vmin = -vmax` which would at least make the center white.

It looks like you might have diverging data (no hard limit), in which case you could look at using one of the [divergent color maps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) (in which case you need to use `center=0` and not `vmin/vmax`).