# Seaborn heatmap only apply to subset of columns

Tags: seaborn, heatmap, pandas-styles

I tried different seaborn functions and pandas `style` functions. I want to apply a heatmap with `center=0` (positive value gets red heatmap, negative values gets blue heatmap) while keeping all the categorical columns uncolored.

When I was using `sns.diverging_palette` together with pandas `style.background_gradient()`, I can specify subset of columns to be colored. But cannot specify the color center as 0.

When using `sns.heatmap()`, [How to set center color in heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56536419/how-to-set-center-color-in-heatmap), it allows you to set center as 0 but the input has to be all numerical....

Is there a method to do both, so that I can apply heatmap to both positive/negative values while keeping the categorical columns uncolored?

Comment: I think `sns.heatmap` needs uniform data types.  You can set `sns.heatmap(data=df['column1', 'column2'])` to have a heatmap for a subset of columns.  Maybe you can create multiple heatmaps, one for each type of data?

Comment: But I need to show both bumerical and categorical columns together....

Comment: Maybe it works if you draw two heatmaps on top of each other? Once you fill all categorical columns with `np.nan`, and once with the numerical columns filled with `np.nan`.  Note that even for a completely numerical dataframe, all columns need to have the same data range for the coloring to work.