# Choosing specific columns while plotting a heat map

Tags: python, matrix, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, heatmap

I have a database that consists of the following columns(parameters),

Power_KW

ReactivePower_kVAr

WindSpeed_mps

YawState

Pitch_Deg

RotorSpeed_rpm

AmbTemp_DegC

WindSpeed1

WindSpeed2

WindSpeed3

SubIprPrivPwrFactor

SubPtchPosition1

SubPtchPosition2

SubPtchPosition3

I was trying to find the correlation using heat map between Power_KW and the rest of the columns, to be exact the heat map consists of 1 column ( `Power_KW`) and the rows are the other parameters.

Here is my code, I'm trying to find a solution but couldn't figure it out I'm fairly new to all of this.

Thank you.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmylK.png)

Comment: Please add code formatted here also example images. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39409866/correlation-heatmap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correlation heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39409866/correlation-heatmap)

Comment: @Joe I'm sorry I'm fairly new to all of this, should I follow the steps done on the linked page? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: This might be related to what you are planning to to. Just read it.

Comment: I tried following the linked page steps, but it is not exactly what i need.