# Heatmap using below code showing black colored columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, heatmap, correlation

I tried to create a heatmap using corr function and background_gradient as below

```
    ibm.corr.style.background_gradient(axis = None,cmap='coolwarm')
```

It is showing matrix with dark black background

[image: Output on display]

Comment: Did you look at [Correlation heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39409866/correlation-heatmap/42323184#42323184)?

Comment: Yes, Did that, result's still the same

Comment: Did you tried to remove `nan`?