# Issue in Coorelation Matrix Heat Map

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, seaborn, visualization

[image]

I am facing this issue in my `heatmap` it only shows values in the first row of the heat map..

I write the following code:

```
    import seaborn as sns
    
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    
    # Select numeric columns
    numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'int64']).columns
    
    # Calculate correlation matrix for numeric columns
    correlation_matrix = df[numeric_columns].corr()
    
    # Add column names as the second row of the correlation matrix
    correlation_matrix.columns = correlation_matrix.columns.values
    correlation_matrix.index = correlation_matrix.columns.values
    
    # Set up the matplotlib figure
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
    
    # Draw the heatmap with the correct display of values
    sns.heatmap(correlation_matrix, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm', fmt=".2f", linewidths=.5)
    
    # Adjust layout for better visualization
    plt.title("Correlation Matrix")
    plt.show()
```

I want someone who can help me to solve this problem..

Comment: This is a known matplotlib bug

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39409866/correlation-heatmap