# python: make a plot of similarity vectors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe

```
          1mbank.ru akbars.ru   alfabank.ru avangard.ru bank-hlynov.ru
1mbank.ru       0.968421053 0.705263158 0.947368421 0.978947368
akbars.ru   0.968421053     0.715789474 0.936842105 0.968421053
alfabank.ru 0.705263158 0.715789474     0.694736842 0.726315789
avangard.ru 0.947368421 0.936842105 0.694736842     0.947368421
bank-hlynov.ru  0.978947368 0.968421053 0.726315789 0.947368421
```

I need to plot a graph, where I can estimate the similarity of this urls.
Scatter plot print all points and it looks not good.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a [heatmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map), which you can do with e.g. [seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) or [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/heatmaps/). The usage is quite straightforward in either case. Or you can even do it with [pure matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282368/plotting-a-2d-heatmap-with-matplotlib).

[image: heatmap of the data frame]