# Resizing imshow heatmap into a given image size in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using `matplotlib` for plotting, and I have the following matrix, `Mat` which I would like to plot into a heatmap.

```
Mat.shape
```

which yields `(20,20)`.

I use the following code to plot it into a heatmap, following the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282368/plotting-a-2d-heatmap-with-matplotlib).

```
plt.imshow(Mat, cmap='Reds', interpolation='nearest')    
plt.show()
```

But I have to resize this heatmap into `1600 x 1200`(x,y) size, since, I want it to be overlapped with the image, `img`. The code is as follows.

```
plt.imshow(img, alpha=.5) # for image
plt.xlim(0, 1600)
plt.ylim(1200, 0)
plt.axis('off')

plt.imshow(Mat, cmap='Reds', interpolation='nearest', alpha=.5)   # for heatmap to overlap
plt.show()
```

For some reason I would not like to change the size of `img`.

---

**My try**

I tried to resize at the level of `plt.imshow(Mat)`, which I found hard. The only option I see at present is to resize `Mat` into `1600 x 1200` matrix with redundancy. Anyone to give me some efficient solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`extent=` parameter of `imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) to scale your matrix to the image's scale ([more information here as well](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html)).

```
plt.figure()
img = plt.imread('stinkbug.png')
plt.imshow(img, alpha=1) # for image
#plt.axis('off')

xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
ymin, ymax = plt.ylim()

Mat = np.random.normal(size=(20,20))
plt.imshow(Mat, cmap='Reds', interpolation='nearest', alpha=.5, extent=(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax))   # for heatmap to overlap
plt.show()
```

[image]