# Plotting csv file in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a csv file that is 200x200. Most of the values are zeros. Somewhere at the center, I have values like this:

[image: one]

Zooming it out further gives this:

[image: two]

Nonzero values form this rectangle(ish) shape.

I want to plot these values with matplotlib so that they look as follows:

[image: three]

Any quick help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Actually I am not sure about the type of graph that would accomplish what I want.

Comment: you should probably show what you've tried. I'm not sure what type of graph you want either. At the minimum, you should be able to use a heatmap.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282368/plotting-a-2d-heatmap-with-matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
plt.imshow(data)
```

The plot has to be a decent size to see the nonzero data, since there are quite a few pixels.