# Create heatmap of matrix using Seaborn matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have exported a large Matrix from Matlab to a `data.dat` file, which is tab delimited. I am importing this data into a iPython script to use `seaborn` to create a heatmap of the matrix using the following [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282368/plotting-a-2d-heatmap-with-matplotlib):

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

uniform_data = np.loadtxt("data.dat", delimiter="\t")
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, linewidth=0.0)
plt.show()
```

This code runs fine and outputs a correct heatmap. For small matrices, the output has a nice variation indicating the matrix elements:

[image: n5_results]

However, if the size of the matrix increases in size, the result seems to have a uniform colour, which indicates that the result needs to be normalised:

[image: n8_results]

which does not seem to contain any extractable information. How can I address this?

Comment: You can `print(uniform_data.min(), uniform_data.max())` to see if those values correspond to the colorbar extremes. (I'm pretty sure they do, because that's how the seaborn code works.)

Comment: You can try lowering vmax to 0.3, the colors will then differ more for lower values but you will not be able to tell if a value is 0.3, 0.5, or 1.0. You can also increase the figure size to make the "heatmap pixels" larger.