# Using python to plot a heat map from five arrays: x,y and 3 arrays indicating RGB

Tags: python, heatmap

I have 2 arrays, x and y, respectively representing each point's coordinate on a 2D plane. I also have another 3 arrays of the same length as x and y. These three arrays represent the RGB values of a color. Therefore, each point in x,y correspond to a color indicated by the RGB arrays. In Python, how can I plot a heat map with x,y as its axes and colors from the three RGB arrays? Each array is, say, 1000 in length.

As an example that takes the first 10 points, I have:

```
x = [10.946028, 16.229064, -36.855, -38.719057, 11.231684, 33.256904999999996, -41.21, 12.294958, 16.113228, -43.429027000000005]
y = [-21.003803, 4.5, 4.5, -22.135853, 4.084630000000001, 17.860079000000002, -18.083685, -3.98297, -19.565272, 0.877016]
R = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
G = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
B = [0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255]
```

I'd like to draw a heat map that, for example, the first point would have the coordinates (10.946028,-21.003803) and has a color of R=0,G=2,B=0. The second point would have the coordinates (16.229064, 4.5) and has a color of R=1,G=4,B=255.

Comment: You want a heatmap for R, another one for G and a third one for B. So three seperate ones ? Do i get you rigth ? Can you explicitly write down the shapes of x and y, are those one column vectors like x = y = [1,1000] and in combination like adjacent matrices, describe all points in the plane. Or are both of them a matrix like [256,256] ?

Comment: @PaulHigazi Sorry I wasn't so clear before. I have updated the question to add an example. I hope this clarifies things. please let me know if it still doesn't make sense. Thanks

Comment: Actually a Heatmap is a color representation of 2D information , so you can get a heatmap of the Red-Channel of an image for example. In your case that would mean 0 is black for example and 9 is white, like a grayscale visualisation. Do you want to combine all three Channels in one Heatmap ?

Comment: @PaulHigazi Right, the color on the heat map should be a color combining the RGB. so in my example the first point which has R=0,G=2,B=0 should have a color very close to black. The second point should have a blue color.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems like you want like your own colormap for your heatmap. Actually you can write your own, or just use some of matplotlibs templates. Check out this [post](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282368/plotting-a-2d-heatmap-with-matplotlib) for the use of  heatmaps with matplotlib. If you want to do it on your own, the easiest way is to recombine the 5 one-dimension vectors to a 3D-RGB image. Afterwards you have to define a mapping function which combines the R-G and B value to a new single value for every pixel. Like:

```
f(R,G,B) = a*R +b*G + c*B
```

a,b,c can be whatever you like, actually the formular can be way more complex, but you have to determine in which correlation the values should be. From that you get a 2D-Matrix filled with values of your function `f(R,G,B)`. Now you have to define which value of this new matrix gets what color. This can be a linear mapping by hand (like just writing a `list:  0=deep-Blue , 1= ligth-Red ...`).  Using this look-up table you can now get your own specific heatmap. But as you may see, that path takes some time so i would recommend not doing it and just use one of the various templates of matplotlib. Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((16, 16))
plt.imshow(a, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

You can use various types of these buy changing the string after `cmap="hot"` to sth of that [list](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html). Hope i could help you, gl hf.