# Stretch matplotlib scatter points vertically in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I have some data in the form of `data[time] = list of y values`.
(data example: `data = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [5, 6, 7, 8]]`)

I want to plot that data using matplotlib in a way that every `y` value will be a dot (square) in the position `(time, y)`.
Currently I'm using `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` to do so
( `plt.scatter(x = [time]*len(data[time]), y = data[time], s=5, marker='s')` ), but the problem is that every square's height is too short, while the width is fine.

Is there a way to control the square's height separately and not both width and height with `s`? (scatter is not required, every plotting way is acceptable)

Example plot:

[image: example plot]

You can see there are vertical spaces between the squares, while there aren't any horizontal spaces.

Comment: `plt.axis('equal')` would make your plot have the same distances in x and in y.  Instead of a scatter plot, you could use `plt.pcolor()` with a 2d array which has zero when there is no value, and 1 when there is a value (or maybe even different values, as your image seems to squares with different colors).

Comment: About `plt.axis`, it doesn't work good here as it just puts all the data in one thin "pipe", but I'll check about `plt.pcolor`, thanks.

Comment: Lots of good answers here: [Plotting a 2D heatmap with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282368/plotting-a-2d-heatmap-with-matplotlib)

Comment: Interesting, will check.