# How to Plot a Surface Graph in Python as in Excel?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have a Matrix of Data consisting of X x Y x Z (hours of day (24) x Energy Meters (21) x Max Demand in Current Amps ).

In excel, I can simply select  the table and make a "Surface graph" which will generate the following representation of the data (3D effect).

It will be my first time programming in Python but I´ve chosen to do it here since it´s compatible with Power BI and other reporting platforms I use.

What python library and plotting options are there for this specific purpose. I´ve researched and tried using some, such as mpl_toolkits, mplot3d but I´m not getting the representation I´m looking for.

[image: Excel Surface Graph]

Comment: I suggest checking heatmaps in seaborn (matplotlib also have them as I remember). [stackoverflow: plotting-a-2d-heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282368/plotting-a-2d-heatmap); [matplotlib doc for heatmaps annotated](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html); you can play with the sizes of the squares [towardsdatascience: heatmaps](https://towardsdatascience.com/better-heatmaps-and-correlation-matrix-plots-in-python-41445d0f2bec)