# How to plot a heatmap/phase diagram with spacing defined by axes coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am trying to plot a phase diagram with the areas of the squares defined by x,y axes coordinates, rather than equally spaced.

For example I have the following arrays:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([ 10,  50, 100, 150])
y = np.array([100,  80,  60,  40,  20,  10,   5])
z = np.array([[0.31, 0.33, 0.34 , 0.34],
       [0.31, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34],
       [0.30, 0.34, 0.35, 0.34],
       [0.30, 0.33, 0.34 , 0.34],
       [0.29, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31],
       [0.29, 0.30, 0.30, 0.29],
       [0.28 , 0.28, 0.28 , 0.29]])
```

I have tried plotting it as a dataframe using sns.heatmap(), but I cannot change the areas of the squares to be sized according to the x,y coordinates instead of equally sized.

I get this result:

heatmap
[image]

I also tried following a suggestion I found here: [Plotting a 2D heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282368/plotting-a-2d-heatmap)
using the code modified here as below, but this way the areas are different but not quite correct:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



z_min, z_max = np.abs(z).min(), np.abs(z).max()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

c = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap='RdBu', vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max, shading='auto', edgecolors='black')
ax.set_title('pcolormesh')
# set the limits of the plot to the limits of the data
ax.axis([x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
fig.colorbar(c, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

which gives this result, this seems almost what I would like but the sqares are not the correct sizes and I cannot quite figure out why:

pcolormesh
[image]

It would be great if I could also annotate the plot with the actual values for each square!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([10, 50, 100, 150])
y = np.array([100, 80, 60, 40, 20, 10, 5])
z = np.array([[0.31, 0.33, 0.34, 0.34],
              [0.31, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34],
              [0.30, 0.34, 0.35, 0.34],
              [0.30, 0.33, 0.34, 0.34],
              [0.29, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31],
              [0.29, 0.30, 0.30, 0.29],
              [0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.29]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')


x_edges = np.append([0], x)#.cumsum())
y_edges = np.append([0], y)#.cumsum())

c = ax.pcolormesh(x_edges, y_edges, z, cmap='RdBu', shading='auto', edgecolors='black')

ax.set_xticks(x) #_edges[1:], x)
ax.set_yticks(y) #_edges[1:], y)

ax.set_title('pcolormesh')
fig.colorbar(c, ax=ax)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap]

Comment: Instead of `ax.set_xticks(x_edges[1:], x)` you can directly use `ax.set_xticks(x)`. The first parameter tells the positions of the ticks, the second parameter indicates labels (strings or numbers) to be placed at those positions.  If positions and labels are the same, it is recommended to leave out the second parameter, making the code more robust against future adaptations.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The `x` and `y` of `pcolormesh` indicate the positions of the *edges* between the cells. If you have 4 cells horizontally, there are 5 edges.

Supposing your given `x` and `y` are cell widths, you can use `np.cumsum()` to calculate the edge positions.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([10, 50, 100, 150])
y = np.array([100, 80, 60, 40, 20, 10, 5])
z = np.array([[0.31, 0.33, 0.34, 0.34],
              [0.31, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34],
              [0.30, 0.34, 0.35, 0.34],
              [0.30, 0.33, 0.34, 0.34],
              [0.29, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31],
              [0.29, 0.30, 0.30, 0.29],
              [0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.29]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x_edges = np.append([0], x.cumsum())
y_edges = np.append([0], y.cumsum())
c = ax.pcolormesh(x_edges, y_edges, z, cmap='RdBu', shading='auto', edgecolors='black')
ax.set_title('pcolormesh')
fig.colorbar(c, ax=ax)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: pcolormesh, widths transformed to edge positions]

The edges can be used to calculate the positions of the centers of the cells, and e.g. label the rows and columns with the x and y amounts.

```py
x_mids = (x_edges[:-1] + x_edges[1:]) / 2
y_mids = (y_edges[:-1] + y_edges[1:]) / 2
ax.set_xticks(x_mids, x)
ax.set_yticks(y_mids, y)
```

[image: adding centered labels to pcolormesh]

Comment: Thank you so much! This was not quite the result I wanted, maybe I just didn't explain properly, but it did point me to the right direction and I managed to have the correct result thanks to you reply! Thanks again a lot! 